# Please find another keyboard shortcut for tables

Tags: feature-request, documentation, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently, in the documentation example editor, the shortcut <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> inserts a table.

However, *anywhere else*, that same shortcut jumps to the end of the line, as a companion to the <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> shortcut to jump to the start of a line. I use that shortcut *all the time* and have to undo the insertion each and every time.

Can we get a different shortcut for a table please?